# Handling Throwable vs. Exception for logging

Tags: java, exception

I'm using a logging package which accepts Exception.  I have a default/uncaught exception handler of my own which of course has to accept Throwable.  If the Throwable is an instance of Exception I can just cast and toss to the logger.  However, if it's a Throwable that won't work.  Currently I'm doing something like the following, but the problem is that the new Exception based on the Throwable loses the stacktrace information.  Is there some way to create an Exception based on a Throwable that retails the stacktrace?

```
if (e instanceof Exception)
    logger((Exception) e); // All good, we get our stack trace logged
else
    logger(new Exception(e)); // Sadness, stack trace missing
```

Comment: Can you modify the logging package?

Comment: The chained `Throwable` should have its own stack trace to log.

Comment: @JonnyHenly There's an intermediate layer that I could modify to accept Throwable, but the 3rd party logger under that only lists it as accepting Exception in the API definition (and that I can't modify)

Comment: Oh gotcha. What about creating a temporary exception via the `Exception(Throwable cause)` constructor and manually filling in the temporary's stack trace? `... else { Exception tmp = new Exception(e); tmp.setStackTace(e.getStackTrace()); logger(tmp); }`?

Comment: I looked at the overloaded `Throwable(Throwable cause)` constructor and it makes a call to `Throwable#fillInStackTrace()` so my last comment seems redundant. Out of curiosity, other than sub classes of `Error`, what other `Throwable` objects are you getting? Are you using throwables as a form of program control flow?

Comment: At first I thought I was only get Exceptions thrown, but to be safe I was making a new Exception from the Throwable for all of them.  I noted that I never got a usable stack trace (it just shows my handler).  So, I switched to just casting and that worked great for a few days until I apparently finally triggered a non-Exception Throwable and double-faulted.  :-)  I see other people saying to just make a new Exception from a Throwable as it will keep the stack trace, but it's not true from what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd party library specifies Exception in the API, but I decided to send it a Throwable anyways to see what happens (since it seems like implementing it internally as Throwable would make a lot more sense).  It still works perfectly fine whether I send in an Exception or a Throwable.  I then flipped my default handler and my intermediate layer to Throwable as well and tested with some known errors.  Still all good.  Not a huge fan of doing things contrary to the defined API, but in this case it appears to be a documentation error or oversight.  Should a future version change the behavior to as defined, maybe I'll be smarter than and be able to figure this out...  :-)